# Use Green’s Theorem to find circulation around C1

Tags: multivariable-calculus, greens-theorem

From the image, I believe that circulation around C1 = Flux of curl F + circulation around C2 + circulation around C3.
We are given curl F = 4, circulation around C2 = 3pi and circulation around C3 = 2pi.

I parametrized C1 as: r(theta)=<5cos(theta), 5sin(theta)> and theta is between 0 and 2pi.
Using Green’s Theorem and curl F = 4 (given) and dA = r dr dtheta, i found that flux of curl F is 100pi.

Therefore, flux around C1 should be 100pi + 3pi + 2pi = 105pi.

Unfortunately, I get the wrong answer but I do not know what I am doing wrong. Any leads?

Attached the working out of the problem so it’s clearer.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You are ignoring the radii of the small circles. Since the curl is nonzero, the radii matter. They should also specify that there are singularities inside the small circles, but you aren’t sure where. Does that matter? Regardless, if you don’t take DougM’s approach, you have to consider things much more carefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\oint_{C_1}F\cdot ds - \oint_{C_2}F\cdot ds - \oint_{C_3}F\cdot ds = \iint \nabla\times F\ dA = 4(23\pi) = 92\pi$

$\oint_{C_1} = 2\pi + 3\pi + 92\pi = 97\pi$

Comment: Where does the 23pi come from ?

Comment: That is the area of the shaded region.

Comment: ok I see thanks ! wouldn't the method I used give the same answer ?